# How in Calendar to display current data according to day instead of displaying the current date

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

please I greatly need your help on how can I, in "CALENDAR", set different datas for each day and display it when the day is clicked. I have checked everywhere and you guys are my last resource. All documentation & example I got are related to "How to get the date selected from the datepicker ". And almost all of them sets the current date as default date in the datepicker.

How can I display current data instead of displaying the current date.

For example,

when one click on:

▪︎28 Dec (it should display) -> "coding is great"

▪︎29 Dec-> "reading is good"

▪︎30 Dec-> "stackoverflow comunity is the best"

Etc...

Pls, help!

Thanks in advance.

I tried to store in onDateSet a data for a particular day, but it is not working. I am New to coding

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How can one set and display different data for each day of the month in a calendar or calendarview. If you know about it, I will be grateful